# Select data between two dates in mysql regardless of year

Tags: mysql, date

I need to select all entries between two given dates (Nov 10 and Jan 25, for example) regardless of year.

It's MUCH easier if it would just be Jan 25 and Nov 10. But how would I structure my query to look for all data between Nov 10 and Jan 25?

Comment: Do you know the year for those dates?

Comment: no i don't know the year for the date range given

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`DAYOFYEAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofyear) function:

```
DAYOFYEAR(field) BETWEEN DAYOFYEAR(A) AND DAYOFYEAR(B)
```

If `DAYOFYEAR(A)>DAYOFYEAR(B)` then your application need either replace `BETWEEN` with `NOT BETWEEN` or else swap the order of the arguments.  If you need to do it in SQL:

```
DAYOFYEAR(field) BETWEEN
   LEAST(DAYOFYEAR(A), DAYOFYEAR(B)) AND GREATEST(DAYOFYEAR(A), DAYOFYEAR(B))
```

Be careful of leap years as the [`DAYOFYEAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofyear) function will take those into consideration

Comment: I just want to mention for others DAYOFYEAR can return different integer for different years like for me: DAYOFYEAR(convert(20000928,date)) <> DAYOFYEAR(convert(20170928,date)).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the exact strings '11 Nov' and '25 Jan', not using any session variables and such:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 
    WHERE c1 BETWEEN 
      DATE(REPLACE(STR_TO_DATE('11 Nov','%d %b'),'0000',YEAR(NOW()))) AND 
      IF( DATE(REPLACE(STR_TO_DATE('25 Jan','%d %b'),'0000',YEAR(NOW())))
          < DATE(REPLACE(STR_TO_DATE('11 Nov','%d %b'),'0000',YEAR(NOW()))),
          DATE(REPLACE(STR_TO_DATE('25 Jan','%d %b'),'0000',YEAR(NOW())+1)),
          DATE(REPLACE(STR_TO_DATE('25 Jan','%d %b'),'0000',YEAR(NOW()))));
```

The above is tested, and crazy.